# Two buttons toggled by their class separately in one fucntion

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#x, #y').click(function() {
        $('#x, #y').toggleClass('try-effect-a try-effect-b');
    })
```

```css
.try-effect-a {
  color: red;
 }
 .try-effect-b {
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='x'>X</button>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='y'>Y</button>
```

Hello there, In my script here i want to change the effect from `a` to `b` in `class` by toggling it,

My problem now is that i want to change only one button per click and not the two of them, Also when i remove the `try-` it doesn't work either

But i want to do it in one function instead of doing two `.click` function for each `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select exact element use `this` as a context. It select's your clicked element.

```js
$('#x, #y').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('try-effect-a try-effect-b');
    })
```

```css
.try-effect-a {
  color: red;
 }
 .try-effect-b {
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='x'>X</button>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='y'>Y</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the part `try-effect-` and keep only `a` and `b` in .`toggleClass`?

Comment: @Axon Then you have to change them in styles too.

Comment: So i have to make the part i want to change separated from the word to be able to use toggle like as i want? Not possible at all while it is a word part?

Comment: @Axon Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: What i understood that i can't toggle the part `a` to be `b` in the class because it is in one word `try-effect-a`, But to be able the toggle only this part i have to make it separated like `try-effect a`, That correct?

Comment: @Axon No you cannot since they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler, `this` is the element instance from the matching selector that the event occurs on

```js
$('#x, #y').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('try-effect-a try-effect-b');
 })
```

```css
.try-effect-a {
  color: red;
 }
 .try-effect-b {
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='x'>X</button>
<button class='btn try-effect-a' type='button' id='y'>Y</button>
```